# Cookies available on different domains / htaccess forwarding

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies

we are running an online portal which is available via different domains (e.g. example.de, example.at, example.ch) as well as variations of it (e.g. exam-ple.de) and payment for all countries is done via secure.example.com, so it is not possible to access cookies on secure.example.com which were set on example.de.

First question (not directly refering to cookies):
Is it possible to forward a user from exam-ple.de to example.de without loosing the referer information? Maybe with .htaccess?

Second question:
Is it "dirty" to store all cookie names in a configuration file and then pass all cookies via GET everytime the user gets forwarded to another domain name and reset the cookies? I can only think of this one solution to make cookies available on different domains... Or does anyone has a better solution for the problem?

Best regards,

Freddy

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906907/php-cookies-for-multiple-domains . Its about your second question

Comment: How do you redirect the urls? Are you using the `Redirect` statement or mod_rewrite?

Comment: I do not redirect at all yet. I just wanted to know whether it is possible at all

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, assuming that you are using apache2 as the web server (you told about .htaccess) , I would suggest using mod_rewrite for redirecting the urls to a different domain. When using mod_rewrite you are enabled to set **cookies**

Also you can create a php script that forwards to your domains and sets the cookies. It might be called like www.yourdomain.com/forward.php?target=at&....